# Java draw stairs using drawRect and using inputField for more stairs

Tags: java, for-loop, drawrect

I'm a beginner whit Java experience so I hope you can help me.

I want to read the number of steps from a JTextfield. But how can you make the stairs variable?

```
Graphics g = textP.getGraphics();

    int x = 5;
    int y = 20;
    int width = 10;
    int height = 10;
```

For loop 1 - whil give a drawRect of 6 pieces

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        g.drawRect(x, y * i, width, height);
    }
```

For loop 2 - whil give a drawRect of 5 pieces

```
    for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
        g.drawRect(x + 15, y * i, width, height);
    }
```

For loop 3 - whil give a drawRect of 4 pieces

```
    for (int i = 2; i < 6; i++) {
        g.drawRect(x + 30, y * i, width, height);
    }
```

For loop 4 - whil give a drawRect of 3 pieces

```
    for (int i = 3; i < 6; i++) {
        g.drawRect(x + 45, y * i, width, height);
    }
```

For loop 5 - whil give a drawRect of 2 pieces

```
    for (int i = 4; i < 6; i++) {
        g.drawRect(x + 60, y * i, width, height);
    }
```

For loop 6 - whil give a drawRect of 1 pieces

```
    for (int i = 5; i < 6; i++) {
        g.drawRect(x + 75, y * i, width, height);
    }
```

Output (must by an rect ipv *):

```
*
**
***
****
*****
******
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way.

```
JTextField stairs = new JTextField("Enter no. of Stairs");
String noOfStairsStr = stairs.getText();
int noOfStairs = Integer.parseInt(noOfStairsStr);
...
for (int i = 0; i < noOfStairs; i++) { // Use that in the for loop.
```

Comment: Yes thats what i try, but it will output 1 line of rects. It must by manny rows of rects (see my added output).

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting  something like this

```
for (int i = 0,k=15; i < 6; i++) {
            g.drawRect( ( x+(i*k) ), y * i, width, height);
}
```

Comment: Yes thats what i try, but it will output 1 line of rects. It must by manny rows of rects (see my added output).

Answer (score 0):

A Graphic environment is complex thing.  No longer do you have the safety of fixed character width and heights, now you need to start dealing with a wider range of environmental factors (such as the width and height of the area you have to paint in...)

To get start I would suggest you take a look at

- [Creating a GUI with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)
- [Performing custom painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)
- [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/)

To cover the basics.

In order to paint steps, we need to know (at least) three things.

1. The number of steps to be painted...
2. The width of each step
3. The height of each step.

This example calculates the width and height of the steps as a factor of the width and height of the container it's painting on.

[image][image][image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class SimpleSteps {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SimpleSteps();
    }

    public SimpleSteps() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JTextField steps;
        private StairPane stairPane;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JPanel options = new JPanel();
            steps = new JTextField(10);
            JButton create = new JButton("Create");
            stairPane = new StairPane();

            options.add(new JLabel("Step count: "));
            options.add(steps);
            options.add(create);

            add(stairPane);
            add(options, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            create.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    String value = steps.getText();
                    try {
                        int stepCount = Integer.parseInt(value);
                        stairPane.setStepCount(stepCount);
                    } catch (NumberFormatException exp) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(TestPane.this, value + " is not a valid step count", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    }

    public class StairPane extends JPanel {

        private int stepCount = 0;

        public StairPane() {
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (stepCount > 0) {
                Graphics g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                int stepHeight = getHeight() / stepCount;
                int stepWidth = getWidth() / stepCount;
                for (int step = stepCount; step != 0; step--) {
                    int width = stepWidth * step;
                    int y = (stepHeight * step) - stepHeight;
                    g2d.fillRect(0, y, width, stepHeight);                       
                }
                g2d.dispose();
            }
        }

        private void setStepCount(int stepCount) {
            this.stepCount = stepCount;
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```